# How to animate android activity background

Tags: android, animation, background

In my android app I want to show a background animation. 
I had done it using images by changing the images with time.
But my problem by using images for each frame of animation the app size was becoming  huge
I know it is not a good way.

I want to do it in efficient and good way.

If I am doing this by using images which is the best way. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Images are always a thing which uses more memory in android. If you are using images there no way by which you can make application to use lesser memory it will just use memory depending on image size, but there is a way which I follow.  If background animation with images was a need then I would use optimized images. Optimization's like using images that suits the screen resolution, size and so on. Further more I would go with having different sized images for different screen resolutions so that size of images would be lesser for lesser screen resolutions. Hope that helps you a bit at least.

Edit :

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) under Using configuration qualifiers you will find about having XML files. You should use timer for that as you need to change the images at timely manner. If you don't want to use timer then go with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html).

Comment: Ok... Is there any XML way to implement this. I have done this with using timer. In each timer interval I will change the background. Can you suggest me some other good way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a while I came to know about this (http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/frame-animation/) solution.